# SilverStripe Dropzone: Cannot delete file

Tags: php, silverstripe, dropzone

I use SilverStripe Dropzone Module for image upload in a front-end form. This is the field:

```
$fields->push(FileAttachmentField::create('ProfileImageID', 'Upload Profile Photo')
    ->setFolderName('Foo')
    ->setValue(null, $this)
    ->imagesOnly()
    ->setPermissions([
        'delete' => true
    ])
);
```

The relation is a has one. I also set the permission for deleting.

```
public function canDelete($member = null)
{
    return Permission::check('ADMIN') || $member->ContactID === $this->ID;
}
```

At first it looks like if I could delete it but if I refresh the page the image appears again. I have no clue what I am missing. Any tips?

Comment: I think i have to overwrite the delete methode?

Comment: Try this instead: `return Permission::check('ADMIN') || ($member->ContactID === $this->ID)`.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! It didn't change a thing.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem is. I have ProfileImage as required field so am actually not able to save if there is none. So Dropzone does not delete the file. As far as i understood Dropzone you have to save to actually delete. I use ZenValidator for validation. I am not sure, but i hope it may help someone else. If i am wrong please correct me.